# How to determine which widget was clicked? Dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

Is there a way to observe the mouse click event and determine which widget was clicked?

So basically I wish I could do something like this (on mouse click anywhere on the page)

```
on("click", function (e) {
   //var aWidget = dijit.getEnclosingWidget(e.target);
   //var id = aWidget.id
   //do something based on the widget id
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can but it will requires some extra steps.
Basically, the logic is:
- When you click on a node, you have to go up in the DOM until you find a node with the attribute `widgetId`
- When you have it, use `dijit/registry::byNode` to fetch the widget.

If you skip the node traversing, you will find the widget only if the main `domNode` of the widget was clicked.

```
require(['dojo/on', 'dijit/registry'], function(on, registry){
    on(document, 'click', function(event){
        var target = event.target,
            widget;
        while(!target.getAttribute('widgetId') && target.parentNode) {
            target = target.parentNode;
        }
        widget = registry.byNode(target);
        console.warn(widget);
    });
});
```

Be aware, this method will work **ONLY** if you have 1 dojo instance loaded on in the page.
If you page have more than one dojo instance then the `document` `click` event must be attached by every dojo instances.

Comment: what do you mean by more than one dojo instance?

Comment: while although this works, I found that when I click on the widget that contains another widget, it only returns the inner most widget.  For example a custom widget that contains a dijit form element returns the form element widget depending where you clicked on the custom widget.

Comment: In some setup multiple dojo versions can be loaded in the same page. If that is your case, you wouldn't be able to fetch the widget with this way.
Obviously dijit are widgets, therefore you will find them when clicking their inner nodes. If you need to find only some specific types of widget, you have to continue going up in the node until the `registry.byNode(target);` gives you an `instanceof` the class you are searching

Answer (score 1):

Might be a lot of overhead but yes you can

```
require(["dojox/mobile/deviceTheme","dojo/on","dijit/registry"],function(theme,on,reg){
    on(document,'click', function(e){
    console.log(e.target);
    var widget = reg.byNode(e.target);
    console.log("foundWidget::" + widget.id);
  });
});
```

Comment: Why the require of `dojox/mobile/deviceTheme` ??

Comment: Not required, just part of my test code so i would get the css:https://jsfiddle.net/omqmLb1s/